# for loops, eval(parse(text = paste0 ... into vectorised lists but keep getting error :attempt to select more than one element in vector Index

Tags: r

This was my original code, very messy and untidy:
[Link to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76410845/how-to-be-concise-in-r-code-1-reading-lists-of-csv-files-2-rename-lists?noredirect=1#comment134738392_76410845)

```
library(dplyr); library(plyr)
library(magrittr); library(stringr) 
library(ExclusionTable)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse); library(tidyr)
library(janitor)
library(survival)
library(ggsurvfit); library(gtsummary)
library(zoo)
library(tidycmprsk)

# AA cohort (2 of 3)
## as

i=1
num_fu = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
as <- data.frame()
df <- data.frame()
dfs <- data.frame()
data_dir <- 'C:/Users/thepr/Documents/data/as'

assign(paste0("flnames", i), list.files(path = paste0(data_dir, i), pattern = "\\.csv", full.names = TRUE))
assign(paste0("as", i, "_list"), lapply(get(paste0("flnames", i)),
                                        function(x){base::as.data.frame(read.csv(x))}))
nm <- gsub(".csv", "", basename(eval(parse(text = paste0("flnames", i))))) %>% str_sub(., 1,6)
assign(paste0("as", i, "_list"), setNames(get(paste0("as", i, "_list")), nm))
df <- Reduce(full_join, get(paste0("as", i, "_list")))
assign(paste0("as",i), df[!duplicated(base::as.list(df))])
dfs <- df

for (i in 2:length(num_fu)){
RID_common <- as1$RID %in% get(paste0("as", i))$RID

      assign(paste0("flnames", i), list.files(path = paste0(data_dir, i), pattern = "\\.csv", full.names = TRUE))
      assign(paste0("as", i, "_list"), lapply(get(paste0("flnames", i)),
                                              function(x){base::as.data.frame(read.csv(x))}))
      nm <- gsub(".csv", "", basename(eval(parse(text = paste0("flnames", i))))) %>% str_sub(., 1,6)
      assign(paste0("as", i, "_list"), setNames(get(paste0("as", i, "_list")), nm))
      df <- Reduce(full_join, get(paste0("as", i, "_list")))
      assign(paste0("as",i), df[!duplicated(base::as.list(df))])
      
      dfs <- merge(dfs, df, by = "RID", all.x = TRUE)
      dfs <- dfs[!duplicated(base::as.list(dfs))]
            if(paste0("AS", i, "_AREA") %in% colnames(get(paste0("as", i)))){
              assign(paste0("fu_",i-1), get(paste0("as", i))[RID_common, c("RID", paste0("AS", i, "_AREA"))])
              assign(paste0("fu_loss_",i-1), get(paste0("as", i))[!RID_common, c("RID", paste0("AS", i, "_AREA"))])
            # FU rate
              assign(paste0("fu_rate_", i-1), nrow(get(paste0("as", i)))/nrow(as1))
            }
            else if(paste0("AS", i, "_DATA_CLASS") %in% colnames(get(paste0("as", i)))){
              assign(paste0("fu_",i-1), get(paste0("as", i))[RID_common, c("RID", paste0("AS", i, "_DATA_CLASS"))])
              assign(paste0("fu_loss_",i-1), get(paste0("as", i))[!RID_common, c("RID", paste0("AS", i, "_DATA_CLASS"))])
            # FU rate
              assign(paste0("fu_rate_", i-1), nrow(get(paste0("as", i)))/nrow(as1))
            }
            else{}
}
```

After helpful comments by @Gregor Thomas @joran, I read previous posts and finally started using lists and vectors. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
library(tidyverse) #Includes: dplyr, stringr, tidyr
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
library(ExclusionTable)
library(janitor)
library(survival)
library(ggsurvfit); library(gtsummary)
library(zoo)
library(tidycmprsk)

# AA cohort (2 of 3)
## as
i=1
data_dir = c("C:/Users/thepr/Documents/data/as")
num_fu = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
dirs <- paste0(data_dir, num_fu) # character
as <- data.frame()
df <- data.frame()
dfs <- data.frame()

flnames <- list.files(path = dirs, pattern = "\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)
as_list[[num_fu]] <- lapply(flnames[[num_fu]],
       function(x){base::as.data.frame(read.csv(x))})
names(as_list) <- gsub(".csv", "", basename(flnames[[num_fu]])) %>% str_sub(., 1,6)
df <- Reduce(full_join, as_list)
df <- df[!duplicated(base::as.list(df))]
```

somehow I keep getting error messages:
`Error in flnames[[num_fu]] :  attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex`

Based on [How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207), I think I am headed in the right direction. Please give some insights and thougths. Will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The code `function(x){base::as.data.frame(read.csv(x))}` is a lot more convoluted than necessary: (1) you don't need the `{}` since the function body is a single expression. (2) you almost certainly don't need `base::`: there should be nothing overriding `as.data.frame`. (3) You don't need `as.data.frame`, since `read.csv` already returns a data frame. (4) You don't need to wrap `read.csv` into a function. — Taken together, you can replace that entire code snippet with just `read.csv`.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph thanks. how do you recommend making `dir` as a list? For example `dir[[1]]` is paste0("data_dir", num_fu[[1]]) ? and etc...

Comment: `num_fu` is the index after the folder name: `as1`, `as2`, `as3`, ... and I want to keep flnames in a list, with names using `num_fu`

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand these comments. However, see the update to my answer, maybe that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[` always selects exactly one element. This is what the error message is trying to tell you.

What you want to do (based on your `num_fu` value) is to *slice* the list to extract a subset. You need to use `[` to do that.

Furthermore, remove the indexing in the assignment target. That is, write:

```
as_list = lapply(flnames[num_fu], read.csv)
```

However, it's unclear that you actually want the indexing here at all, since it does not correspond to anything that I understand. Don't you simply want the following instead?

```
as_list = lapply(flnames[num_fu], read.csv)
```

---

Alternatively, if you want the entire thing in a *nested* list, where each subdirectory has its own sub-list, there are several solutions. One would be the following (note the nested invocation of `lapply`):

```
flnames = lapply(dirs, list.files, pattern = "\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)
as_list = lapply(
  flnames,
  function (subdir) {
    setNames(
      lapply(subdir, read.csv),
      sub("\\.csv$", "", basename(subdir)) %>% str_sub(., 1,6)
    )
  }
)
```

etc.

However, I would instead recommend keeping the structure flat. And, especially if you want to subsequently merge the entire thing into one single data.frame, you can drastically simplify *the entire code* as follows:

```
data_dir = "C:/Users/thepr/Documents/data/as"
num_fu = 1 : 9
dirs = paste0(data_dir, num_fu)
files = list.files(dirs, pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)


df = purrr::map_dfr(files, read.csv, .id = "Filename") %>%
  mutate(Filename = str_sub(sub("\\.csv$", "", basename(Filename)), 1, 6))
```

(Incidentally, avoid mixing `=` and `<-` for assignment, it makes the code messy; [you can use either one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51564252/1968), just don’t mix them.)

Comment: I have tried your latest code, but this appears:  `In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/thepr/Documents/data/as1': Permission denied`. I think the reason is that `dirs` contain only path to a folder, not individual files.

Comment: On the other hand, `flnames = lapply(dirs, list.files, pattern = "\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)` works perfectly, as I wanted flnames to be lists of 9 folders, each having their files as nested lists

Comment: Oops, yes, I had forgotten the `list.files` function call in that code. I added it now.